# WebDeploy not taking changed files, only new files

Tags: iis-7, sitecore, sitecore6, web-deployment

I'm using WebDeploy to push physical files to a target location when doing a publish from the SiteCore CMS. I'm having some problems though,

- WebDeploy only pushes newly created files, but not any files that have changed
- It's using the admin agent service which requires an AD admin account to run. Is there a way to make it use the IIS agent instead? (I think that this may be related to SiteCore itself)
- If it isnt possible to get it working with the IIS agent, then is it possible to make it use a local account instead of requiring an AD admin account?

Comment: @SayedIbrahimHashimi, I wonder why did you added a slowcheetah tag here?

Comment: Was trying to categorize related questions, but now I see just an answer mentioned it. Removed tag :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that you must use the admin agent service for Web Deploy in Sitecore.
I have spent many hours trying to work around this, but it seems impossible.
This does indeed require a local admin account to be used (which sucks..)
This issue has been discussed with Sitecore on several occasions and i hope they will come up with a better solution in future releases.

When properly set up, Web Deploy will also push updated files.
There is a command line utility that comes with web deploy which you can use to test the installation.
Try to get everything to work using that utility and then try it again in Sitecore.
Make sure you test using the admin service.
Can you also confirm that the date/time settings on both servers are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Not precisely on-topic, but have had mixe results with Web Deployment.  I switched to using the Publication method, along with SlowCheetah XML Transforms (which allows you to do build transforms on any XML file for your build configuraton) and it works really well.

Plus it runs under the authority of the developer running VS (or the account running the build script).

Plus it has features for "replace whole directory" or "update as needed".

...just sayin...